# how to implement Zoom View by PanResponder in react native

Tags: react-native, pinchzoom, panresponder

I want Implement Zoom View by PanResponder in react native
i just want to use React native Animated API and PanResponder API.
Thanks so much
I want to implement a view Component , that view can use 2 fingers to zoom in and out

I want Implement Zoom View by PanResponder in react native

Comment: you can read this tutorial : https://javascript.plainenglish.io/react-native-image-zooming-with-gesture-handler-376193e3d3b4

Comment: Please also read https://stackoverflow.com/tour